# Gitlab CI/CD: fatal: bad config line 4 in file /builds/xxxxxxx/software/flask_api_for_mampok/.gitmodules

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have this error when running the gitlab pipeline after a commit.
`fatal: bad config line 4 in file /builds/xxxxxxx/software/flask_api_for_mampok/.gitmodules`

The file looks like this:

```
[submodule "metadata-organizer"]
    path = metadata-organizer
    url = ../metadata-organizer.git
[submodule "mampok"]
    path = mampok
    url = ../mampok.git
```

The problem is, I didn't see any mistake in that file and tried removing and re-adding the submodules too.
The weird part is that I get the same error, even when deleting that file.

Comment: Line 4 does look fine here. You might inspect it in something that will show you any odd otherwise-invisible characters (e.g., a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor)). Also, check whether there's any filtering going on that might mess with things, e.g., git-lfs or git-crypt or some other add-on.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it. It wasn't anything wrong with the `.gitmodules` it was somehow an error of the gitlab runner. Setting up a new runner solved it.